# Magento 2. How do i put out of stock products to the end in catalog search result collection?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I tried to do it via layer collection :

> $collection->getSelect()->order('is_salable DESC');

It works for catalog, but does not sort the result in search .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this layer plugin:

```
public function afterGetProductCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject,
    $result
)
{
    $collection = $result;
    if(!$this->_added) {
        if($this->isCatalogSearchCollection() && $collection && $this->useSelect()) {

            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['stock_item_table' => $collection->getResource()->getTable('cataloginventory_stock_item')],
                "e.entity_id = stock_item_table.product_id",
                ['is_in_stock']
            );
            $collection->getSelect()->order('is_in_stock DESC');
            $orders = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
            array_unshift($orders, array_pop($orders));
            $collection->getSelect()->setPart(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER, $orders);
            $this->_added = true;
        }else{
            $collection->getSelect()->order('is_salable DESC');
            $this->_added = true;
        }
    }
    $result = $collection;
    return $result;
}
```

And i also added a class variable that comes up as false when class init, then after order is has been placed to avoid circle select and order method call:

```
 protected $_added = false;
```